# Apache POI (or similar) support on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Does google app engine suppout apache POI ?

Can I create excel files using the POI framework that a user can then download ?

Answer (score 0):

I've used Apache POI successfully on GAE for PowerPoint Docs .pptx. Can't speak, for Excel files but the Java libraries for POI had no issues. There were a lot of dependencies that had to be resolved but nothing too challenging.

Comment: Might you consider sharing your port of Apache POI?